# Let $f$ be a real function and let $A$, $A\subset \mathbb R$, be a countable dense set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a real function and let $A$ be a countable dense subset of $\mathbb R$.

Assume that the function $f$ is continuous on $A$.

Put $D:=\{x\in \mathbb R\setminus A : f \text{ is continuous at }x\}$.

Prove or disprove the following cases.

**(i)** The set $D$ is non-empty.

**(ii)** The set $D$ is dense in $R$.

Comment: By R; do you mean $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R$ is the biggest set of that kind. $(\forall D\subset \mathbb R) \;D\;\text{is countable and dense}\implies D^c \;\text{is uncountable & dense}$

Comment: The vertical line in the first edited version means either $\mathbb R$ divides A or  ':' is redundant. You can use either | or : . $\setminus$ is used for the set difference. I wrote defined because it is shorter, but "continuous at $x$" is totally fine because it is in harmony with the definition od $D$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the set $S$ where $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous is always a $G_\delta$.

In fact, $S=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}W_n$, where
$$
W_n=\big\{x\in\mathbb R : \exists\varepsilon>0(y,z\in\big(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\to|f(y)-f(z)|<\tfrac{1}{n}\big)\big\}
$$
and all the $W_n$'s are open.

A dense countable set $A=\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, which is a subset of a $G_\delta$ has to be a proper subset, since the $G_\delta$ itself has to be dense, and hence in our case each of the $W_n$'s has to be dense. But, $W_n\setminus\{a_n\}$ is also dense in $\mathbb R$, and hence 
$$
\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} (W_n\setminus\{a_n\})=
\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} W_n\setminus A=S\setminus A,
$$
is also dense, since it is also a dense $G_\delta$. (This is due to Baire's Theorem.)

So, both statements, (i) and (ii), and correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

We know that since $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}, \forall x\in \mathbb{R},\delta>0,\exists a\in A$ such that $a\in\delta-$neighbourhood of $x.$ Can we say something similar for $x\in A$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$?

How does this help?